# Why is subprocess.run recommended over check_output when it is less concise?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

According to the latest documentation for the python subprocess module at https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module, `run` is recommended to be used instead of the older `check_output` function.

> The recommended approach to invoking subprocesses is to use the run()
> function for all use cases it can handle. For more advanced use cases,
> the underlying Popen interface can be used directly.

In the documentation for [check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) the equivalent run command is like this:

```
run(..., check=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout
```

Why is this `run` call which requires additionally importing `PIPE`, passing 2 extra arguments and then calling `.stdout` recommended over just importing and running the more concise `check_output` function?